# Project Server 2019 cannot setup AD Enterprise Resource Pool Sync

Tags: project-server, profile-sync

I have a newly setup Project Server 2019. The SharePoint farm is installed in **sharepoint**. It has one-way trust domain with **company** and all my users is under **company/PWAmembers** AD group.

We have run STSADM.exe to configure the people-picker. So that both domain's members can show up in people picker.

Then I setup my first site collection with PWA feature:
Enable-SPFeature pwasite -URL https://pwa.sharepoint.com

Then in **PWA settings > Active Directory Enterprise Resource Pool Synchronization**, I typed in "PWAm...." and the people picker can automatically resolved to "**company/PWAmembers**" which is the correct AD group I would like to setup.

When I click "Save" it throws and error `The People Picker field contains unresolved or local entities, please correct this.` and not allow me save and sync.

Here is the related ULS logs:

```
PWA:http://sharepoint.com/sites/PWA,User:08782c3f-41b9-ea22-bebc-005056a08cdd-ADSyncERP picker ResolvedEntities: <name>c:0+.w|s-1-5-11-2125374196-150106210-10358574-2401</name>
PWA:http://sharepoint.com/sites/PWA,ServiceApp:Project Server Service Application, PSI: ActiveDirectoryUtility::TryGetGroupInfoByClaim: Calling GetFqdnFromSid
PWA:http://sharepoint.com/sites/PWA,ServiceApp:Project Server Service Application, PSI: Failed to determine fqdn/netbios mapping of server COMPANY.  exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007052E): The user name or password is incorrect
PWA:http://sharepoint.com/sites/PWA,ServiceApp:Project Server Service Application, PSI: ActiveDirectoryUtility::TryGetGroupInfoByClaim: Calling TryGetGroupInfo(<name></name>, <name><SID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx></name>, null)
PWA:http://sharepoint.com/sites/PWA,ServiceApp:Project Server Service Application, PSI: Failed to retrieve information about Active Directory Group on the AD server. Check with your Active Directory admin to see if the AD object still exists. domain: , searchPath: '<SID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>', searchFilter: '', exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005000): Unknown error (0x80005000)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, you configure people picker properly ?

PWA:http://sharepoint.com/sites/PWA,ServiceApp:Project Server Service Application, PSI: Failed to determine fqdn/netbios mapping of server COMPANY.  exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007052E): **The user name or password is incorrect**

What kind of AD group is it? Domain local, global?

Comment: It is a global security group. Right after create the group, I can find it in the people picker (by type in PWA...) so I think I configure it correctly. However, it worth a try to retype the password.

Comment: I can successfully add PWAmembers in "Team lead in PWA" group. So I think my people picker configuration is correct. Only error is occur in AD Enterprise Resource Pool Sync's picker.

Answer (score 1):

Project Server's Active Directory Enterprise Resource Pool Synchronization only support follow condition:

1. The domain in which your SharePoint Server/Project Server farm is currently installed.
2. A domain that has a **two-way** trust relationship with the domain in which your SharePoint Server/Project Server farm is currently installed.

So one-way trust is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason, if two-way trust relationship present, can be network polices and blocking of some ports between domains, which will prevent successful synchronization. Unfortunately, I can't say exactly which ports, but a similar problem in my practice was solved at the level of network engineers, and not the Project Server admin.